# How could I remove/close multiple tabpanels at once in RShiny?

Tags: shiny, tabpanel

How could I remove/close multiple `tabpanels` at once? I make an `RShiny` apps where users can make queries. The queries will be shown in `tabpanels`. They can close one `tabpanel` or multiple `tabpanels` at once. But the code for the latter doesn't work. In this question I enclose the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. Many thanks in advance for your help.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        actionButton(inputId = "btnNewQuery",
                     label   = "New query"),
        actionButton(inputId = "btnCloseTabpanel",
                     label   = "Close tabpanel"),
        actionButton(inputId = "btnCloseAllTabpanels",
                     label   = "Close all tabpanels")
    ), 
    br(),
    fluidRow(
        tabsetPanel(id = "tabsetPanel_Queries", type = "tabs")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    # Button: New query =====
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$btnNewQuery, {
            showModal(
                modalDialog(
                    title = "Queryname",

                    textInput(
                    inputId = "txtQueryname",
                    label = "Queryname",
                    value = "",
                    width = "600px",
                    placeholder = "Fill in the queryname."),

                    footer = tagList(
                                 modalButton("Cancel"),
                                 actionButton(
                                     inputId = "btnQueryname_OK",
                                     label   = "OK")),
                    easyClose = TRUE
                ) #modalDialog
            ) #showModal
    }) 

    # Button: OK (of the messagebox) =====
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$btnQueryname_OK, {
        removeModal()
        shiny::appendTab(
            inputId = "tabsetPanel_Queries",
            select  = TRUE,
            tabPanel(
                inputId = input$txtQueryname,
                title   = input$txtQueryname,
                value   = input$txtQueryname,
            ) #tabPanel
        ) #appendTab
    })
        
    # Button: Close tabpanel =====
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$btnCloseTabpanel,{
        if(!is.null(input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])){
            shiny::removeTab(inputId = "tabsetPanel_Queries",
                         target  = input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])}
    })

    # Button: Close all tabpanels =====
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$btnCloseAllTabpanels,{
        # This code doesn't work. It stays remain in a loop.
        while(!is.null(input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])){
            print(input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])
            shiny::removeTab(inputId = "tabsetPanel_Queries",
                             target  = input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])}
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following codes work:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)


ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        actionButton(inputId = "btnNewQuery",
                     label   = "New query"),
        actionButton(inputId = "btnCloseTabpanel",
                     label   = "Close tabpanel"),
        actionButton(inputId = "btnCloseAllTabpanels",
                     label   = "Close all tabpanels")
    ), 
    br(),
    fluidRow(
        tabsetPanel(id = "tabsetPanel_Queries", type = "tabs")
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
    tab_list <- NULL

    # Button: New query =====
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$btnNewQuery, {
            showModal(
                modalDialog(
                    title = "Queryname",
                    textInput(
                        inputId     = "txtQueryname",
                        label       = "Queryname",
                        value       = "",
                        width       = "600px",
                        placeholder = "Fill in the queryname."),
                    footer = tagList(
                        modalButton("Cancel"),
                        actionButton(
                            inputId = "btnQueryname_OK",
                            label   = "OK")),
                    easyClose = TRUE
                ) #modalDialog
            ) #showModal
    })


    # Button: OK (of the messagebox) =====
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$btnQueryname_OK, {
            removeModal()

            tab_title <- input$txtQueryname
    
            shiny::appendTab(
                inputId = "tabsetPanel_Queries",
                select  = TRUE,
                tabPanel(
                    inputId = input$txtQueryname,
                    title   = input$txtQueryname,
                    value   = input$txtQueryname,
                ) #tabPanel
            ) #appendTab
    
            tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)
    })


    # Button: Close tabpanel =====
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$btnCloseTabpanel,{
            if(!is.null(input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])){
                shiny::removeTab(inputId = "tabsetPanel_Queries",
                                 target  = input[["tabsetPanel_Queries"]])}
    })


    # Button: Close all tabpanels =====
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$btnCloseAllTabpanels,{
            print(tab_list)

            tab_list %>%
                walk(~removeTab("tabsetPanel_Queries", .x))

            tab_list <<- NULL
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```